# Vue.js - Is model binding in the template the way to go for me?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, vue.js

So my task at hand is probably pretty simple, but as I'm new to Vue.js, I'm not sure what is best practice in this situation.

I'm building a template, for generating some content. At the moment, I have my template defined, and it takes certain inputs:

```
<basic-dashboard 
        dimensions="ga:date" 
        metrics="ga:sessions"
        start="30daysAgo"
        end="yesterday"
        container="chart-container"
        type="LINE"
        width="100%"
    >

    </basic-dashboard>
```

At the moment, I'm just binding these template inputs into props:

> ```
> Vue.component('basic-dashboard', {
>         template: '#basic-dashboard-template',
> ```

```
        props: ['metrics', 'dimensions', 'start', 'end', 'container', 'type', 'width'],

    });
```

and using them in hidden HTML elements, which isn't really optimal:

```
<template id="basic-dashboard-template">        
    <div id="defMetrics" hidden>{{ metrics }}</div>
    <div id="defDimensions" hidden>{{ dimensions }}</div>       
    <div id="defStartDate" hidden>{{ start }}</div>
    <div id="defEndDate" hidden>{{ end }}</div>
    <div id="defContainer" hidden>{{ container }}</div>
    <div id="defType" hidden>{{ type }}</div>
    <div id="defWidth" hidden>{{ width }}</div>     
</template>
```

I would much prefer, if I could save these into variables in my javascript, for later use in another javascript - The question is, how would I go about doing this in the best way? My Initial thought has been to use model-binding, but I'm not sure that is the correct approach here, since I technically don't want to change the inputs in the script - I just want to make a template, that can define these variables, and same variables should be useable in a later defined javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to give default values to all of your props?

Comment: I could, but at the moment I'm just thinking that if you do not define a certain value, the template will fail - The most important thing is to somehow skip the hidden HTML elements, and make use of the defined 'props', in a later defined javascript.

Comment: @HowDoiJava i don't understand, why you need a component then. You can simply save data in object. Or if you need data after page refresh use html5 storage or something similar

Comment: The component is used to generate a dashboard, using the Google API - The thought behind it is, that it would be an easy-to-use component template, where a user just fills out the template values, and when the code is executed, these values are then used in a later javascript, that generates the google analytics charts

Comment: What would be the relationship between the "later defined javascript" and this component? Can it see the component? The parent of the component?